# Set 'url title' of a view

Tags: list-view, client-object-model, url

How to set the url title of a list view programmatically (preferrably CSOM/JSOM) so we could for example create a view whose View Name is "My View" and its web address ends with "/MyView.aspx"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code sample should help:

```
SP.ViewCreationInformation viewCreationInformation = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
viewCreationInformation.Title = "My View";
viewCreationInformation.ViewTypeKind = SP.ViewType.None;
viewCreationInformation.RowLimit = 30;

//Make sure that the name of the fields should be equal to 1 any of the associated SiteColumns Internal Name. The Fields in the view will appear in the same order as declared here.
viewCreationInformation.ViewFields = new string[]{"Title","Created","Modified"};
viewCreationInformation.SetAsDefaultView = true;

oList.Views.Add(viewCreationInformation);

ctx.Load(oList.Views);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you want the URL and Title to be different, you might need to play a trick with SharePoint..

That is first create the view with title "MyView" and then get the view again and update the Title value to "My View"..

Comment: Can we change the url of an existing view?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.. SharePoint stores the URL and even if you update the Title, it won't change the URL..